# ctags not working for vim from command line

Tags: ubuntu, vim, ctags

I have built tags for my project folder using

```
ctags -R *
```

After the tags file is generated for all files in my project folder I am able to use tags via Ctrl + ] and Ctrl + T after opening a file.
However, when I try to open a file using tags it somehow does not work !!

```
vim -t <filename>
```

The above commands opens the vim editor saying 'tag not found' when the file actually exists there and is reachable via tags if I open another file referencing it and use Ctrl + ].

What could I be missing here ?

Comment: Did you read `:help -t`?

Comment: Consider offloading the duty to deal with ctags to plugins: "Vim: convenient code navigation for your projects": http://dmitryfrank.com/articles/vim_project_code_navigation

Comment: @DmitryFrank thanks for the link on vim code  navigation.

Comment: On a side note: `ctags -R` works fine and does what you want.  `ctags -R *` on the other hand may run into problems, depending on the names of the files in the current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-t` option requires a **tag** and not a **file**.

---

```
vim -t Tag
```

This will first search for you the **file** where the **definition** of `Tag` is located based on the **tags** file already created by `ctags` command then open it.